# Ошибка в Encoding.Unicode

Tags: c#

Имею код:

```
byte[] one = new byte[] {215, 170, 8, 223, 101, 20, 107, 124};
byte[] two = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(one));
foreach (var el in two)
    Console.Write(el + " ");
```

На выходе:

```
215 170 253 255 101 20 107 124
```

Как видно, третий и четвёртый байты не совпадают. Баг или фича?

Comment: Почему бы не выложить код текстом?

Comment: А вы уверены, что входные байты представляют валидное значение для получения из них строки?

Comment: @АндрейNOP при использовании BitConverter.GetBytes(BitConverter.ToChar(...)) по два байта выходные данные совпадают с входными.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это фича. С настройками по умолчанию UnicodeEncoding не проверяет входящие байты на валидность. Т.е. строку вы получаете, но т.к. на входе могли быть байты, не имеющие валидного отображения в строку, то в строке на этой позиции будет 0xFDFF (253, 255).

На самом деле поведение при встрече невалидного символа зависит от Encoding, и его можно заменить на кастомный. Для Unicode, это Replacement Fallback. Если нужны подробности - посмотрите [MSDN, Character Encoding in .NET, Replacement Fallback.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding#Replacement)

Если хотите получать ошибку, а не "невалидный символ" - укажите throwOnInvalidBytes при создании кодировки:

```
var encoding = new UnicodeEncoding(false, false, throwOnInvalidBytes: false);
encoding.GetString(new byte[] { 215, 170, 8, 223, 101, 20, 107, 124}); // бросит исключение
```

Comment: Благодарю, за то, что помогли разобраться

Comment: А есть пример, когда использование этого символа будет валидно?

Comment: @Grundy для стандартных кодировок - да, для ascii там будет валидный backspace :)

Comment: @PashaPash, Ну не :-) в ascii backspace это только 8 :-) 223 это уже другой символ будет. Я имел ввиду, если это суррогатная пара из какого-то блока low surrogate, значит если она идет вместе с какими-то символами, она может быть валидной? или влиять на отображение предыдущего или последующего символа?

Comment: о, _Their use is restricted to UTF-16._ так, что похоже в этом случае нельзя :) или наоборот - можно?